# How to connect URM37 (rangefinder) to Arduino and read data through nodeJS

Tags: node.js, arduino, firmata

I bought this range finder http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/URM37_V3.2_Ultrasonic_Sensor_(SKU:SEN0001)

And now I'm having difficulties to make it work on nodeJS.
My setup is Arduino UNO and nodeJs using "firmata" library.

What have i tried:
1. I tested the Rangefinder with native Arduino IDE and it worked.
2. Then i wrote data to EEPROM from Arduino IDE(code exmaple below):

```
int cmmd1[]={
  0x44,0x00,0x10,0x54};//low byte stored in the sensor for the distance threshold.
int cmmd2[]={
  0x44,0x01,0x00,0x45};//high byte, write 0x0010 into address 0x01 and 0x00,so the threshold is set to 16cm
int cmmd3[]={
  0x44,0x02,0xaa,0xf0};// Autonomous mode. write 0xaa into address 0x02
//int cmmd3[]={
//  0x44,0x02,0xbb,0x01};  // PWM mode. write 0xbb into address 0x02
int i;

void setup(){                                 
  Serial.begin(9600);                         // Sets the baud rate to 9600
  A_Mode_Setup();                             //PWM mode setup function
}

void loop()
{
}                      

void A_Mode_Setup(){ 
  //write the data into the URM37 EEPROM
  for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    Serial.write(cmmd3[i]);                             
  delay(200);                                           

  for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    Serial.write(cmmd1[i]);
  delay(200);

  for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    Serial.write(cmmd2[i]);
  delay(200);

}
```

1. I tried to make the same code as it was in the manual to make it work but in nodeJS, and i failed:

   ```
   var board = new firmata.Board('/dev/cu.usbmodemfd121', function() {

   var command = [0x44, 0x02, 0xbb, 0x01];

   board.pinMode(5, board.MODES.OUTPUT);

   board.digitalWrite(5, board.HIGH);

   board.pinMode(3, board.MODES.INPUT);

   board.sp.write(command, function(err, results) {
       console.log(arguments)
   });

   var callback = function() {
       console.log(arguments);
       //console.log(this)
   }

   board.on('pulse-in-3', callback);

   board.on('pin-state-3', callback);

   board.pulseIn({
       pin: 3,
       value: board.LOW,
       timeout: 50
   }, callback);

   setInterval(function() {
       board.digitalWrite(5, board.LOW);
       board.digitalWrite(5, board.HIGH);

   }, 100);
   ```

   });

Please Guys help me!

Comment: Can you explain what is not working. Do you get errors from node.js?

Comment: If i digitalRead pin 3 some times i get error argument 1 and sometimes 0 but no values...(((( but in this case it siple does nothing